# Webkit issue - scaling is causing elements on top of a video to disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video, css-transforms

I have a container div, and inside it:

- a video element
- a red square div on top of the video, in the top-right corner

Demo available here:
https://jsfiddle.net/r5zLyuxh/6/

The container has a `transform:Scale()`, and `overflow:hidden`.

When you start increasing the scale, you will notice that somewhere between scale 1.1 - 1.2 - the red box div disappears!
It is still there, but it's moved to be behind the video.

1. Happens in **Chrome & Safari**, both on desktop and mobile browser.
2. Happens only for elements located on the right side of the video.
3. Increasing the z-index doesn't help. Only when setting the video to be `z-index:-1` it will show the red element.
4. When replacing the video element with a simple div, the issue doesn't happen.
5. When removing the `overflow:hidden`, the issue doesn't happen.

*Any idea why this is happening?*

Due to production limitations, **i am looking for a global css/js fix to apply to the container, and not to the children elements**.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Me and my colleagues are having the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?